# jQuery looping inputs issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a function that auto focuses an input field when the page is loaded and reloaded.

I have existing code that when an input box is filled out and it loses focus, the page reloads.  It will then put focus back into the first input box and this is an issue I want to correct.

In the main body of the Jquery load function I call focusForm();

```
function focusForm() {
        $('#txtFName #txtLName #txtDistID #txtPostalCode #txtEmail').each(function () {
            var currVal = $(this).val();
            if (currVal == '') {
                $(this).blur();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

What I am trying to accomplish is, when the page is loaded/reloaded it will check each input, when it finds one that has no value it will focus that box.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery selector is doing what you think it does? To me it looks like you're finding the `#txtEmail` element, which is inside the `#txtPostalCode` element, and so on... So you're only selecting a single element within a hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `$('#txtFName, #txtLName, #txtDistID, #txtPostalCode, #txtEmail')` to select all of the different elements. The selector you used looks for an element with id `txtEmail` inside one with id `txtPostalCode` inside `txtDistID` inside `txtLName` inside `txtFName`.

Also, I think you want `focus` instead of `blur`.

Comment: Mark his response as the correct/best answer. Make it a habit to do that for all of your questions that are answered

Comment: Won't let me for another 5 minutes.